# PHP - create function issue

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables, quotations

I'm trying to understand this code and I can't :(

```
$time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$what = create_function('$a', 'return $a.'.'"'." AND date > '$time'".'"'.';');
```

Why does the `$time` variable get passed successfully in this created function, but when I try:

```
$limit = 10;
$what = create_function('$a', 'return '.'"'." LIMIT '$limit'".'"'.';');
```

`$limit` doesn't ?

ps: if I try `$what = create_function('$a', 'return '.'"'." LIMIT 10".'"'.';');` it works...

Comment: You must be missing something - As far as I can tell, it should work as you expect.

Comment: To be 100% sure you could try: `'return '"LIMIT ' . $limit . '";'` . Note that there should be no quotation marks around the number after to `LIMIT` (in the SQL), making your string concatenation and quotation orgy much simpler ;) (but even if you don't concatenate `$limit`, the first and the last concatenation are superfluous: `'return "'." LIMIT '$limit'".'";'`)

Comment: `'.'` makes no sense in a `'` quoted string when just appending strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code can be much simplified:

```
$what = create_function('$a', "return \"LIMIT $limit\";");
```

or

```
$what = create_function('$a', 'return "LIMIT ' .  $limit .'";');
```

The code should work. Note that the number after `LIMIT` must not be enclosed in quotes in the SQL syntax.

But as you are creating a function, you could also pass `$limit` as parameter to the function:

```
$what = create_function('$limit', 'return "LIMIT $limit";');
$str = $what(10);
```

or don't use `create_function` at all and just do string concatenation directly:

```
$str = 'LIMIT ' . $limit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems a little messy when your concatenating strings, try a simpler approach:

```
create_function('$a', sprintf('return "LIMIT %d"',$limit));
```

if you don't mind me asking, why are you creating a function to return a simple string ?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to read and to difference between `'` and `"` in your example.

Try this:

```
$what = create_function('$a', "return \"LIMIT $limit;\"");
```

As well as

```
$what = create_function('$a', 'return \'LIMIT $limit;\'');
```

Or

```
$what = create_function('$a', 'return "LIMIT '.$limit.';"'); // most clear, I think
```

You can use `\` as escaping character, this means the next character after this will not be interpreted as a closing quote if it is the current quote character.

Example:

```
echo '\''; // will output '
echo '\"'; // will output \"
echo "\""; // will output "
```

Comment: Both won't work and the second one would not do what the OP wants. And you have to return a string. In it's current form you will get an error.

Comment: The second one will not work because `$limit` is not a local variable of the function, created by `$what`.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested your second code, and it works, correctly passing in `$limit`:

```
<?php
$limit = 10;
$what = create_function('$a', 'return '.'"'." LIMIT '$limit'".'"'.';');
echo $what(2);// note: `2` was randomly chosen, and used because $what expects an argument
// result: ` LIMIT '10'`
?>
```

The above `$what` line can be rewritten as:

```
$what = create_function('$a', 'return "' . " LIMIT '$limit'" . '";');
```

Beware that you do not accidentally write it as (note the quote characters around `$limit`:

```
$what = create_function('$a', 'return "' . ' LIMIT "$limit"' . '";');
```

In that case, `$limit` does not get substituted by `10` (value of `$limit`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am wondering why you are using [`create_function`](http://nl.php.net/create_function)? If there is any chance (and there usually is), you should try to avoid it, since this generally results in very sloppy code.

**The first thing I notice is that your second example doesn't do anything with `$a`:**

```
$what = create_function('$a', 'return '.'"'." LIMIT '$limit'".'"'.';');
```

Should probably be:

```
$what = create_function('$a', 'return $a . '.'"'." LIMIT '$limit'".'"'.';');
```

Also, when concatenating strings, try surround the `.` by spaces. It will make your code more readable (and thus, debugabble). Lastly, go easy on the double and single quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

In create_function, `$limit` is in single quotes; either you should include it in double quotes (`"LIMIT $limit"`) or use the concatenation (`.`) operator (like this: `'".$limit."'`).

Comment: Thanks Chris, You did great work. Atleast, some people still care.